# If $T$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ and $T$ has all its eigenvalues real, then can I say $T$ is not normal?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\Bbb V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ and $T$ is a linear operator on $\Bbb V$

I know that if $T$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ then $T$ is not normal.

My question is if $T$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ and $T$ has all its eigenvalues real, then can I say $T$ is not normal?

I think the conclusion is valid given that if all the eigenvalues are real then $T$ has *no excuse* for not being diagonalizable if it's normal. I mean, if $T$ was normal you could take $\Bbb V$ as a $\Bbb C$-vector space just for the sake of diagonalizing it and then going back to $\Bbb R$. There wouldn't be any problem as the diagonal form of $T$ has all real values on its diagonal. But for this you need $\Bbb V$ to be both a $\Bbb C$-vector space and a $\Bbb R$-vector space right? What would happen with $\Bbb R^n$, for example?

Comment: There's the issue as to whether the matrix you conjugate by to get the diagonal real matrix over $\mathbb C$ has imaginary entries.

Comment: Could you expand a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A normal matrix with real eigenvalues is symmetric, and real symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable.

You're talking about an operator on a real inner product space, which we may identify with $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard inner product.  We can then reduce the problem to a question about matrices with real entries.  But an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with real entries automatically also acts as an operator on $\mathbb C^n$, so a normal matrix with real eigenvalues will be self-adjoint as a complex $n$-by-$n$ matrix, hence symmetric when all its entries are real.

Comment: I don't really understand the answer

Comment: @Shomar: Thank you for the feedback.  If you would like to be a little more specific about what isn't clear, I could try to help clarify.

Comment: I think the main difficulty is that this answer answers the question (yes or no) only implicitly. The opening sentence of this answer implies: yes, you can say $T$ is not normal, since if it were, the matrix of $T$ in an orthogonal basis would be symmetric hence diagonalisable (over the reals), which by assumption $T$ is not.